# How to Configure allure report with Specflow in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: testing, automation, specflow

I am trying to automate testing of my project using specflow. I want to use allure report to show the details of the test cases. When I configure allure report in VS 2019, It is showing me so many errors and exception. Can someone provide proper link or steps to be followed. I am using NUnit testcases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 1 example on this problem hope it will help you all. [Example of How to configure allure report with specflow](https://github.com/Ukrainis/SeleniumSpecflowAllureTest/tree/master/TestAutomationSolution)